# Cast an array (Component to JMenuItem) doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I have an Array that contains `Component` elements. I can take one specific element (e.g. array[0]) and cast that to an `JMenuItem`. But I cannot cast the complete array by using

```
newArray = (JMenuItem[]) componentArray;
```

Does anyone know, why its working with a single element but not with the complete array?
I need to convert the array to access the JMenuItems - I cannot get the name of the object from the component.

Hope someone understand me and can help me with that!

Comment: Because that's a downcasting and it won't work in arrays unless the array is indeed a `JMenuItem[]` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the `Component` array somewhat as follows the cast won't work and will give you a `ClassCastException` :

```
Component[] componentArray = new Component[10];
```

but if you create it as follows, you won't get an exception:

```
Component[] componentArray = new JMenuItem[10];
```

However, if you still want to use the first one and also get an array of `JMenuItem` you can do it as follows:

```
JMenuItem[] newArray = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(componentArray, componentArray.length, JMenuItem[].class);
```

Here is the full sample code:

```
    Component[] c = new Component[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        c[i] = new JMenuItem(""+i);
    }
    JMenuItem j[] = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(c, c.length, JMenuItem[].class);
```

Comment: @user3649938 Please accept is as an answer then by clicking on the tick. :)